# Are processes the same as concurrency in django-post_office?

Tags: django, concurrency, celery, multiple-processes, django-postoffice

I am using [django-post_office](https://github.com/ui/django-post_office) to send c.10,000 emails in a single task each morning.

It's possible to do this via the function `send_queued(processes=1, log_level=None)` in a celery task.

I understand it's best practice to run celery with concurrency, e.g. `celery -A settings worker -l info --concurrency 6`

Is the `processes` flag in `django-post_office` the same as this? E.g. if I am running `6` concurrent celery processes should I have this flag also set as `6`?

If not, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Did you look into post_office code?

Answer (score 1):

`send_queued(processes=6)` will split the number of emails to send into 6 groups and handle each group independently in a process using `multiprocess.Pool`.

`celery --concurrency 6` will run 6 celery processes. Each process will be able to handle one task at a time. It will not affect how your emails are dispatched because `send_queud()` is one instruction executed in one celery process. However if you had multiple celery tasks (executing `send_queued()` or not) queued at the same time, these tasks will be able to run concurrently (at a maximum of 6) instead of waiting for the previous tasks to be terminated before running another.

In other words `process` argument of `send_queued()` and `--concurrency` argument of `celery` are completely unrelated.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't this mean that each celery concurrency is a daemonic process and so are the `send_queued()` processes? I thought python didn't allow child daemonic processes?

Comment: No, `send_queued()` uses `multiprocess.Pool`, nothing to do with daemonization.